# Append to last line of file

Tags: sas

In the below code, is there an easy way to append to the last line of the file without using the @ symbol?  I want to do this all in a single data step.

```
data _null_;

  file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\test.txt" lrecl=1000;

  do cnt=1 to 10;
    put cnt;
  end;

  put #10 "append to last line";   

run;
```

For some reason my code is advancing the line pointer by 10 lines instead of going to line 10.  Am I misinterpreting [the help doc](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1spe7nmkmi7ywn175002rof97fv.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p10usuhkyaf20kn1mlh49gbgywbb) ?  And even if it did go to line 10, how would I move the column pointer to the end of the line?

Desired result:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10append to last line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#` operator works *relative to the current line*. SAS writes files in a linear fashion, always moving forward never moving backwards, unless you tell it to hold the line pointer (with `@` or `@@`).  Note that if you don't have the `@` in Dom's example, you don't get the desired behavior either: that's because he's keeping the line pointer on row one the whole time.

So you basically have two choices: always move forward, or hold the line pointer and tell SAS to write to various lines ahead of the held line pointer.  You use `@` or `@@` to hold the line pointer (not across or across data step boundaries).

The only way to write to a line without `@` is to write the bit before the `;` on put, which you'd have to write code to do I suppose:

```
 data _null_;

  file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\test.txt" lrecl=1000;

  do cnt=1 to 9;
    put cnt;
  end;
  put cnt +(-1) "append to last line";


run;
```

But that seems sort of like cheating.

Answer (score 3):

Only way I can get the output from the toy problem is to use the `@` symbol.  I suppose this is not an answer:

```
data _null_;

  file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\test.txt" lrecl=1000;

  do cnt=1 to 10;
    put #(cnt) cnt @;
  end;

  put +(-1) "append to last line";   

run;
```

In this case, the `#` functions as expected, moving the output to the desired line with `@` holding the pointer there after writing.  Subsequent `put` statements can then append to that line.

Why it doesn't work in your problem example is beyond me.

Without this method, I don't think there is an easy way to append to a line without keeping track of the length of each line.  You could build a hash table for each line and store the length as you print it.  That would let you know what column you would need to start writing to later.

Comment: Actually the code I have can be easily modified to work using your solution.  I marked Joe's as accepted because he confirmed that there's no way to go backwards.  But I'm going to modify my code based on your answer.